# Using Angular4 as server side render engine

Tags: node.js, angular, angular-universal

I have a very big system today written in Nodejs, express, mongoose and pug.

I wish to transfer the system to use Angular4 instead of pug so I can enjoy the possibilities to render my views on both front and back ends. As well as having a robust components system and all the other abilities of Angular4.

As a first step I wish to only replace pug with Angular4. I have read few articles and tutorials showing how to render Angular4 on the server side.
I wish to know how can I currently make the replacement and just keep all the BL in the nodejs layer and pass the final view model to angular for it to render.

Would love to know if there is an "easy" way doing that,
thanks,
Matan

Answer (score 0):

In back end(node+express) you might have path for routing, say for CRUD operation you have some routing. Now come to my point in Angular 4. Set up the Angular framework(You can use CLI or get a clone from git quick start [quick start](https://github.com/angular/quickstart)) in the service of angular call the API of back end you have just created. Now you can interact with the back end by Angular instead of pug. Now you have got the freedom to work on front end.
 - Hope this concept will help you.

Answer (score 0):

best way:

1. npm install angular-cli -g
2. ng new your-project-name (**--style=scss** to set default scss)
3. if you want to use pug as default - [look this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48556518/install-use-pug-jade-angular-2-for-cli-version-no-custom-webpack/48556519#48556519)
4. create app.routing.ts side by side with app.module.ts
5. fill it:

   import {Routes, RouterModule} from '@angular/router';
   import {NotFoundComponent} from './404/404.component';
   import {AppComponent} from './app.component';

   const routes: Routes = [{
       path: '',
       component: AppComponent
     }, {
       path: '**',
       component: NotFoundComponent // need to create it
     }
   ];

   export const Routing = RouterModule.forRoot(routes);
6. in app.module.ts add this:

> **import {Routing} from './app.routing';**
>
> ```
> @NgModule({
>   imports: [
>     ...
>     **Routing,**
>     ...
>   ],
>   ...
> ```

7. for start use ng serve (--port=3000)(--base-href='/')(--env=prod)(--sm=false)
   --sm=false -> no source map, as a result, the weight will decrease (but there will be no references to errors, useful for production)